# Python jupyter webserver stops after 3-5 seconds

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How I installed jupyter:

```
pip install --upgrade pip

pip install jupyter
```

After I ran:

```
jupyter notebook
```

It opens a tab in my firefox browser and brings me to the jupyter notebook and the output on the command line is:

```
C:\Users\Owner>jupyter notebook
[I 23:07:15.090 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Owner
[I 23:07:15.090 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.2.0 is running at:
[I 23:07:15.090 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=6381c19dc8bd8d2687358935960a866af154c171af9bb5b2
[I 23:07:15.090 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=6381c19dc8bd8d2687358935960a866af154c171af9bb5b2
[I 23:07:15.090 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 23:07:15.173 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-10788-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=6381c19dc8bd8d2687358935960a866af154c171af9bb5b2
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=6381c19dc8bd8d2687358935960a866af154c171af9bb5b2
```

After about 3-5 seconds, in the command line jupyter stops running and I am returned back to

```
C:\Users\Owner>
```

in the command line. Like the jupyter program stops running, and the webserver then of course is also down after the 3-5 seconds.

Windows 10
Python 3.7.5

[image]

Comment: Any additional logs you can see in the terminal?

Comment: Nope, I added a photo of the whole 10 seconds it runs, then stops.

Comment: Try creating a global virtualenv, install jupyter and run, might work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have many modules installed, so I just reinstalled python and it seems to work. I tried some other things with no success, not the best solution but atleast I got it working.